# Ng-option directive cant get access to nested array value

Tags: arrays, angularjs, nested, ng-options

Help

I'm trying to output different class options(economy/business) with ng-options.
Here is the  syntax and  json information .
Cant get it working

```
<select ng-model="mySelect" ng-options="item for item in items ">
</select>
```

```js
  $scope.items = [
   {
    "id": 2,
    "codeName": "class",
    "friendlyName": "Class",
    "options": 
    [

      {
        "id": 15,
        "displayOrderNo": 0,
        "optionName": "Economy"
      },

      {
        "id": 16,
        "displayOrderNo": 1,
        "optionName": "Business"
      },

      {
        "id": 36,
        "displayOrderNo": 2,
        "optionName": "First Class "
      }
    ]
   }
  ];
```

Comment: Can you make plnkr or jsfiddle for this? I can't understand what You want. You have 2 `select`, in 1 You select `item` & in 2, select `option`, or You want select 2 models in one `select`?

Comment: You want a dropdown of `"Economy"`, `"Business"`, `"FirstClass"`? Then you need `ng-options="item for item in items.options"`

Comment: Here a link to the the plunker page [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/UVORR2gKJKHUHLb6slG6)

Comment: yes thats it, trying to simple get the class populated in the ng option

Comment: plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/UVORR2gKJKHUHLb6slG6?p=info

Comment: Got there in the end using the following

Comment: <select ng-model="mySelect" ng-options=" item.optionName   for item  in items[0].options ">